# Как написать функцию на jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, алгоритм

Только начал изучать JS и jQuery, нужна небольшая помощь.
У меня есть две html страницы первая содержит кнопку или линк, при нажатии на неё должна открываться вторая страница, и должен добавиться атрибут 'checked', к тегу с определенным классом, а с других инпутов удаляться:

1.html

```
<a class="link_1" href="2.html"> CLICK ME </a>
<a class="link_2" href="2.html"> CLICK ME 2 </a>
<a class="link_3" href="2.html"> CLICK ME 3 </a>
```

2.html

```
<input type="radio" id="tab1" class="input_1" name="tab-control">
<input type="radio" id="tab2" class="input_2" name="tab-control">
<input type="radio" id="tab3" class="input_3" name="tab-control">
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.link_1').click(
                $('.input_1').attr('checked',true)
                );

   $('.link_2').click(
                $('.input_2').attr('checked',true),
                $('.input_1').removeAttr('checked','checked')
                );
               
    $('.link_3').click(
                $('.input_3').attr('checked',true),
                $('.input_1').removeAttr('checked','checked'),
                $('.input_2').removeAttr('checked','checked')
                );
    });
```

всегда выполняется последняя функция то есть атрибут 'checked' добавляется к input_3 при нажатии на любой линк.

```
<input type="radio" id="tab1" class="input_1" name="tab-control">
<input type="radio" id="tab2" class="input_2" name="tab-control">
<input type="radio" id="tab3" class="input_3" name="tab-control" checked="checked">
```

Пробывал вызвать событие .on('click'), но тоже не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё гораздо проще. Добавляете Вашим ссылкам дополнительный параметр (#) со значением, которое соответствует классу радиобаттона:

```
<a class="link_1" href="2.html#input_1"> CLICK ME </a>
<a class="link_2" href="2.html#input_2"> CLICK ME 2 </a>
<a class="link_3" href="2.html#input_3"> CLICK ME 3 </a>
```

При переходе на страницу с батонами получаете этот параметр и выделяете нужный батон:

```
let href = window.location.href.split('#').pop(); //получаете значение доп.параметра

$('[type="radio"]').each(function(){ //в цикле проходите по батонам
    if($(this).attr('class') == href) { //если класс соответствует доп.параметру
        $(this).prop('checked', true); //выделяете батон
        $('[type="radio"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false); //с остальных снимаете выделение
    }
})
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, это заработало, у меня была такая идея, но я никак не мог написать правильно функцию которая получает этот параметр.

Comment: только если вдруг Вы решите добавить ещё какие-то классы для батонов, то это перестанет работать )) лучше для подобных вещей использовать data-атрибуты

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript работает только на том страницу которий тот момент открит, то есть евент не будет работать на втором страницу если обязательно чтоб так било нужно при клике на localstorage у сохранит нужний елемент и при загрузки страницу проверит если есть данний инпуит класса на нему и дать параметр например

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.link_1').click(function (e){
            localStorage.setItem('check','.input_1')
        });
        
    });
```

и при загрузке второго страницу нужно

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
       
            if(localStorage.getItem('check')){
                $("input").removeAttr("checked");

                $(localStorage.getItem('check')).attr('checked',true);
                

            }
    });
```

За акцент извините

Comment: Интересно, он срабатывает но только на 1 инпут, не могли бы подсказать чтобы он работал на все 3 инпута?

Comment: да просто нужно сделать такое   
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.link_1').click(function (e){
            localStorage.setItem('check','.input_1')
        });
   $('.link_2').click(function (e){
            localStorage.setItem('check','.input_2')
        });
   $('.link_3').click(function (e){
            localStorage.setItem('check','.input_3')
        });
        
    });
Ето измените на первом страницу все дольжно работать уже